# Using Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket to download file from internet?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I want to using Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket to download file from internet.
I need a source template.
Anyone help me!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a couple of minutes to read [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), as well as the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It will help you post better questions.

Comment: do you want to download the file over HTTP, much like a browser does? you can use Poco's HTTPClientSession for that, see docs [here](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPClientSession.html)

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me:

```
#include "Poco/URIStreamOpener.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include "Poco/Path.h"
#include "Poco/URI.h"
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPStreamFactory.h"
#include "Poco/Net/FTPStreamFactory.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using Poco::URIStreamOpener;
using Poco::StreamCopier;
using Poco::Path;
using Poco::URI;
using Poco::Exception;
using Poco::Net::HTTPStreamFactory;
using Poco::Net::FTPStreamFactory;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  HTTPStreamFactory::registerFactory(); // Must register the HTTP factory to stream using HTTP
  FTPStreamFactory::registerFactory(); // Must register the FTP factory to stream using FTP
  
  string url = "http://somefile.mp3";
  string filePath = "C:\\somefile.mp3";

  // Create and open a file stream
  std::ofstream fileStream;
  fileStream.open(filePath, ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);

  // Create the URI from the URL to the file.
  URI uri(url);

  // Open the stream and copy the data to the file. 
  std::unique_ptr<std::istream> pStr(URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri));
  StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), fileStream);

  fileStream.close();
}
```

A lot of the above came from the example code found [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/devel/Net/samples/download/src/download.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on page 11 of the [Poco network slides](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf), it should help to get you started.